# React reducer that does not update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

From a Redux tutorial I've been going through they allow you to add a place multiple times.  I changed the reducer to reject duplicates.  My question is, (see code), do I have to return the state if no updates are made or is there some other way of indicating no state is changed?

```
function placeReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PLACE:
        const existing = state.places.find((item) => item.value == action.payload);
        if (existing) {
            return {...state};
        }
        return {
            ...state,
            places: state.places.concat({
                key: Math.random(),
                value: action.payload
            })
        };
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just `return state` instead of `return {...state}`. Reducer, at its core, is just a function splitting out result state based on an input action and an input state. If no state is changed, just return the input state.

Comment: ok.  That seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the state, no need to create a new copy.